# Convert nil interface to pointer of something in Golang?

Tags: pointers, interface, go

In the following code piece, trying to convert a nil interface to a pointer of something fails with the following error: `interface conversion: interface is nil, not *main.Node`

```
type Nexter interface {
    Next() Nexter
}

type Node struct {
    next Nexter
}

func (n *Node) Next() Nexter {...}

func main() {
    var p Nexter

    var n *Node
    fmt.Println(n == nil) // will print true
    n = p.(*Node) // will fail
}
```

Play link here: https://play.golang.org/p/2cgyfUStCI

Why does this fail exactly? It's entirely possible to do

```
n = (*Node)(nil)
```

, so I'm wondering how can you achieve a similar effect starting from a nil interface.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This is because a variable of *static* type `Nexter` (which is just an interface) may hold values of many different *dynamic* types.

Yes, since `*Node` implements `Nexter`, your `p` variable *may* hold a value of type `*Node`, but it may hold *other types* as well which implement `Nexter`; or it may hold *nothing* at all (`nil` value). And [Type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) cannot be used here because quoting from the spec:

> `x.(T)` asserts that `x` is **not `nil`** and that the value stored in `x` is of type `T`.

But `x` in your case is `nil`. And if the type assertion is false, **a run-time panic occurs**.

If you change your program to initialize your `p` variable with:

```
var p Nexter = (*Node)(nil)
```

Your program will run and type assertion succeeds. This is because an interface value actually holds a pair in the form of: `(value, dynamic type)`, and in this case your `p` will not be `nil`, but will hold a pair of `(nil, *Node)`; for details see [The Laws of Reflection #The representation of an interface](http://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection#TOC_3.).

If you also want to handle `nil` values of interface types, you may check it explicitly like this:

```
if p != nil {
    n = p.(*Node) // will not fail IF p really contains a value of type *Node
}
```

Or better: use the special "comma-ok" form:

```
// This will never fail:
if n, ok := p.(*Node); ok {
    fmt.Printf("n=%#v\n", n)
}
```

Using the "comma-ok" form:

> The value of `ok` is `true` if the assertion holds. Otherwise it is `false` and the value of `n` is the zero value for type `T`. **No run-time panic occurs in this case.**