# How to make a variable with this data type and value in Golang? Pointer to a struct with a nil value?

Tags: unit-testing, go, pointers, struct, null

I am doing a unit test, but I found this data type that I don't understand.

```
Error:          
       Not equal: 
                 expected: <nil>(<nil>)
                 actual  : *pkgname.StructName((*pkgname.StructName)(nil))
```

FYI, pkgname is a name of a package, StructName is a name of a Struct

How do I make a variable with the same datatype and value of "***pkgname.StructName((*pkgname.StructName)(nil))**"?

Is it a pointer of struct to a nil value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't mention which testing framework or method you use, but judging from the error, most certainly the mistake is that you expect a `nil` value (without type), and you get a `nil` pointer value which has a pointer type with a concrete base type.

To fix it, you should expect a typed `nil` value, and not a `nil` interface value (without type).

For example:

```
actualValue := ... // Execute function / method / whatever, obtain testable value

// Test it the way you do
// (Here I assume you do it with a function named expectEqual):
expectEqual((*pkgname.StructName)(nil), actualValue)
```

Note that `(*pkgname.StructName)(nil)` is a type [conversion](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Conversions), it converts the `nil` (pointer) value to `*pkgname.StructName` pointer type.

See related questions:

[Convert nil interface to pointer of something in Golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30162256/convert-nil-interface-to-pointer-of-something-in-golang/30162432#30162432)

[Hiding nil values, understanding why golang fails here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29138591/hiding-nil-values-understanding-why-golang-fails-here/29138676#29138676)

Comment: Great answer! This is what I looking for. Yes I haven't understand (*pkgname.StructName)(nil) but now i understand